# how to run a compiled CPP file with geany

Tags: compiling, execute-command, geany

I have recently compiled a .CPP file with Geany. The result file is a .o file. How can I run this .o program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually can't run a `.o` (object code) file directly: it lacks the necessary library linkage.

Instead of `Compile`, you need to `Build` (Geany shortcut <kbd>F9</kbd> rather than <kbd>F8</kbd>). This will produce an executable file with default name the same as your CPP file but without the `.cpp` extension.

You should then be able to run it within Geany's shell using `Execute` from the Geany `Build` menu, or shortcut <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: it works but the result file didn't run when i click it so what should i do?????

Comment: it just run with geany but not when i try to open it from home folder

Comment: @khaled IMHO that's a different question - it concerns the behavior of your file manager rather than being anything to do with Geany

Comment: so how can i fix this behavior so that i can run it without opening Geany

Comment: @khaled You could `chmod +x filename` and then, from command line, `./filename`? This sets the "executable" permission on the file and then runs it.